# Get current page URL hash variable to button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, url

I have this javascript code:

```
<script>
var burl = location.search;
</script>
```

It fetches variables after ? from my page url http://example.com/index.xhtml?hash=37393 which is = hash=37393 and it creates a button with this javascript code:

```
 <script>      
document.write('<input type="button" name="hash" value="' + burl + '" id="buttonjs" style="font-weight: normal; font-family:Verdana,sans-serif; font-sizes:15px;line-height:1.5; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; text-align: center; background: green; border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; color: white; font-weight: bold; border: 3px; width: 100%; box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black; border-radius: 16px;"/>');      
</script>
```

Is there any way i can make the code fetch only the hash variable from page url which is 37393 ?

Comment: Sure, just use `location.hash` instead

Comment: Any code to test? I prefer examples... :)

Comment: @adeneo um, that is not the hash OP is talking about. Wrong dupe...

Comment: @adeneo: They mean the `hash` query parameter.

Comment: Squint is right! Any help?

Comment: See the new dupe, use the code there in the selected answer. With the code from the selected answer it is just `getParameterByName("hash")`

Comment: @Reuben: This has been asked about many times before, and your question has been closed as a duplicate of one of those. The answer is easily found by performing a simple Google search.

Comment: I'd be glad if i can get a link to one. I made a search before coming here, couldn't find a genuine answer.